# scrapy how to count all the 300 redirects

Tags: python, scrapy

Is there a way i can do this in a smaller code?

***spider.py***

```
    ...
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301,302,303,305,307,308,400,403,404]


    ...

        item['redirects'] = 0

        if response.status == 301 or response.status == 302 or response.status == 305 or response.status == 307 or response.status == 308:
            item['redirects'] += 1
```

Basically i want to count ALL the 300 redirects

Comment: Define "smaller". Is your goal to decrease the complexity / runtime of your code or do you only want the written text / filesize to decrease ("minify")?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks to make a working code smaller. This may be a proper question for the code review site at stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

```
if response.status in [301, 302, 305, 307, 308]:
    item['redirects'] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below

```
if 301 <= response.status <= 308:
```

Or you can use below

```
if response.status in (301, 302, 305, 307, 308):
```

Basically anything 3XX is considered a redirect related code